# EC2内でdocker buildが成功しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

EC2内でdocker buildを成功させたいです．
詰まるところは毎回まちまちで
- nokogiri
- puma
ここの２つのどちらかで詰まっている様子です．

その時のエラーが

```
Fetching nokogiri 1.10.7
Installing nokogiri 1.10.7 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200109-10-m1jupr.rb extconf.rb
Cannot allocate memory - /usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200109-10-m1jupr.rb
extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.7), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.7' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails_admin was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
    rails was resolved to 5.2.4.1, which depends on
      actioncable was resolved to 5.2.4.1, which depends on
        actionpack was resolved to 5.2.4.1, which depends on
          actionview was resolved to 5.2.4.1, which depends on
            rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
              nokogiri
The command '/bin/sh -c gem install bundler && bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 5
```

となっています．
以下に，DockerfileとGemfileを載せておきます．
よろしくお願いします．

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev \
  nodejs

ENV APP_DIR /project_name
RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR
WORKDIR $APP_DIR

COPY Gemfile $APP_DIR
COPY Gemfile.lock $APP_DIR

RUN gem install bundler && bundle install

COPY . $APP_DIR

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-p", "3000", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 2.0'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'cocoon', '1.2.12'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'gon'
gem 'enum_help'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'debase'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'hirb-unicode'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-doc'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'rails_best_practices'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'letter_opener_web'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'database_rewinder'
  gem 'rspec-request_describer'
  gem 'autodoc'
  gem 'json_spec'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: "Cannot allocate memory" とエラーが出ていますから、メモリが十分割り当てられているかをまず確認してみるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます．メモリを増やすことでうまくいきました．

Comment: 解決したようでなりよりです。回答として改めて投稿し直しておきましたので、もしよければ [回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントにも投稿しましたが改めて。

エラーメッセージの先頭で "Cannot allocate memory" と出ているので、メモリの割り当てが足りていない可能性があります (現象の発生がまちまちなのも恐らくこのため)。

設定状況を確認の上、メモリの割り当て量を追加してみてください。